# Python logging and Monitoring?

Tags: bash, python-2.7

How to Monitor?
Is there any way to run a script that will log and if a certain thing changes  it takes action only python and or Bash shell

Comment: What are you trying to monitor?  File changes?  Network activity?  Activity of some program or the OS?  Function calls within a program you wrote?

Comment: I am trying to monitor and if a certain word shows it takes action

Comment: What is the source of text that you want to monitor?